# Google Maps V3 API not working in MVC5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to ASP.NET MCV5 and trying to add Google Maps to get direction from my current position to some destination.

The code below is working fine when I am running it alone in an html file but not working in ASP.NET MVC5 project in .cshtml view. I tried to change `http` to `https` in in Google Maps library as suggested in another question, but it is still not working. Any suggestions, please.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
                <title></title>
                <style type="text/css">
                    body
                    {
                        font-family: Arial;
                        font-size: 10pt;
                    }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var source, destination;
                    var directionsDisplay;
                    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
                    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
                        new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtSource'));
                        new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtDestination'));
                        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ 'draggable': true });
                    });

                    function GetRoute() {
                        var mumbai = new google.maps.LatLng(18.9750, 72.8258);
                        var mapOptions = {
                            zoom: 7,
                            center: mumbai
                        };
                        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'), mapOptions);
                        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
                        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('dvPanel'));

                        //*********DIRECTIONS AND ROUTE**********************//
                        source = document.getElementById("txtSource").value;
                        destination = document.getElementById("txtDestination").value;

                        var request = {
                            origin: source,
                            destination: destination,
                            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
                        };
                        directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                            }
                        });

                        //*********DISTANCE AND DURATION**********************//
                        var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
                        service.getDistanceMatrix({
                            origins: [source],
                            destinations: [destination],
                            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                            unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
                            avoidHighways: false,
                            avoidTolls: false
                        }, function (response, status) {
                            if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK && response.rows[0].elements[0].status != "ZERO_RESULTS") {
                                var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
                                var duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;
                                var dvDistance = document.getElementById("dvDistance");
                                dvDistance.innerHTML = "";
                                dvDistance.innerHTML += "Distance: " + distance + "<br />";
                                dvDistance.innerHTML += "Duration:" + duration;

                            } else {
                                alert("Unable to find the distance via road.");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                </script>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            Source:
                            <input type="text" id="txtSource" value="Bandra, Mumbai, India" style="width: 200px" />
                            &nbsp; Destination:
                            <input type="text" id="txtDestination" value="Andheri, Mumbai, India" style="width: 200px" />
                            <br />
                            <input type="button" value="Get Route" onclick="GetRoute()" />
                            <hr />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <div id="dvDistance">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div id="dvMap" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div id="dvPanel" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br />
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Have you opened the browser's F12 developer tools and are you getting any Console errors or having issues with any resources loading in the Network log?

Answer (score 0):

click F12 check in console what error is showing .This google map api may required Google API Key.But it is working   fine in .cshtml